Strange result about cut off pair example of phono3py
I have tried the phono3py silicon example with quantum Espresso but while using the mesh grid of $11\times11\times 11$, I obtained the thermal conductivity of 124.29. I have also tried the cut off pair of 5A and I got 124.83, which is strange. Note that I have used the same input file as in the tutorial.
Please, I would also like to know if the thermal conductivity always increases with the increasing of the number of supercell?

+1. Welcome to our community.

Welcome! Why is this strange? What result did you expect?

in the tutorial, the result using the cutoff pair of 5 was about 108 but i am getting about 124.  Also i was expecting the result of the thermal conductivity to increase with the augmentation of the supercells.

I have also try to take the cutoff pair of 2A, and the thermal conductivity is 104.88 with only 3 supercells. does it means that the number of supercell does not really matter? can someone use the smallest cutoff pair number to approximate the value of the lattice thermal conductivity?
